# Spring WebFlux doOnSuccess/doOnError/onErrorContinue never executed

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm creating a reactive endpoint where some actions need to be performed. I want user to see an exception only 'retrieveServiceByParam' fails, but any other error shouldn't be returned, only added in the logs.
This is my controller:

```
private final Map<String, MyUseCase> myUseCase; //map of the different implementations of my service

retrieveServiceByParam(param)
    .doOnNext(
        useCase ->
            useCase.doSomething(xxx)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
    .subscribe();

return retrieveServiceByParam(param).find().then();


private Mono<MyUseCase> retrieveServiceByParam(final String param) {
  return MyEnum.find(param)
      .doOnError(
          throwable -> {
            throw new NotFoundException("xxx");
          })
      .map(myUseCase::get);
}
```

Here's the use case implementation (where the doOnError/doOnSuccess is not executed):

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> doSomething(final InputValues inputValues) {
  return Mono.when(
          firstAction(xxx),
          secondAction(xxx)
      .onErrorContinue((throwable,o) -> log.error("ERROR"))
      .doOnSuccess(a -> log.info("SUCCESS"));
}
```

Both firstAction and secondAction return Mono and no matter if they fail or are successful, the onErrorContinue or doOnSuccess are never executed.

If in the controller I put everything in the 'return' statement, the 'doOnError'/'doOnSuccess' are executed correctly, but then the API returns an error if anything in the useCase fails (which I don't want it to).

Comment: Where is doSomething used?

Comment: It's the method in the useCase

Comment: If i think correctly - doOnNext expects void response and does not subscribe to doSomething result